# Customizing individual layer's width in Plotly Icicle chart

Tags: plotly-python, icicle-diagram

Is it possible to customize the width of individual layers in Plotly Icicle chart?
For example in the chart below, how can we reduce the width of the first layer on the left?

[Plotly Icicle chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4E3m5.png)

I tried changing branchvalues or even changing the figure/page width but it seems none of these parameters can change the default behavior of the Icicle chart which is allocating equal width to all layers.